# A single method to delete! elements from Array by predicate and return deleted

Tags: ruby

I couldn't find a method in docs to do the following:

```rb
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a.remove! {|x| x > 1}
puts a # [1]
puts b # [2, 3]
```

There is a `select!` method that does similar thing but it doesn't accept a predicate.
To my disappointment, `delete_if`, `keep_if`, `reject!` and `select!` mutate the array but also return the same array.

Currently, I achieve a desired in 2 steps like this but maybe there are better/smarter options?

```rb
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a.reject {|x| x > 1}
a = a - b
puts a # [1]
puts b # [2, 3]
```

Comment: In your `a.remove!` example you are mutating `a` whereas in the `a.reject` example you are setting `a` to a newly-created object. Sometimes it makes a difference, so you should clarify which behaviour you want or state that either is acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know a way to accomplish that in 1 step, however if as in your 2nd example you'd accept to not mutate `a` from the ruby method, you could use [Enumerable#partition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition)

```
a = [1, 2, 3]

# note that b is first because first array is for elements returning true
b, a = a.partition { |x| x > 1 }

puts a # [1]
puts b # [2, 3]
```